# Oracle trigger does not allow Inserts on table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

An "After Insert"  oracle trigger stops any inserts that meet a certain condition. The trigger is checking the column "CLASS_TIME" and if it is less than 9 am or greater than 6 pm then update the inserted row. But the row is not inserted altogether hence its not possible to update the same row. Below is the trigger code

```
create or replace TRIGGER ENFORCE_CLASS_TIMINGS 
AFTER INSERT ON SYSTEM.TUTPRAC 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD1 NEW AS NEW1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( 
  to_number(to_char(to_date(NEW1.CLASS_TIME,'hh24:mi'),'sssss')) < 
    to_number(to_char(to_date('09:00', 'hh24:mi'), 'sssss')) OR
  to_number(to_char(to_date(NEW1.CLASS_TIME,'hh24:mi'),'sssss')) > 
    to_number(to_char(to_date('18:00', 'hh24:mi'), 'sssss')))

BEGIN

  UPDATE SYSTEM.TUTPRAC
    SET STAFFNO = NULL
  WHERE
    CLASSID = :NEW1.CLASSID;

    COMMIT;
END;
```

Please suggest how to fix it.

Comment: this should be a before insert and you should not be creating tables in system schema as  a best practice

Comment: What is the data type of column `CLASS_TIME`?

Comment: The datatype of column class_time is varchar2

Comment: If it is that very row that you want to change the value on, then just do this as a BEFORE INSERT trigger and simply set :NEW1.staffno := null; You don't need to fire another update statement. Also, leave COMMITs out of triggers! Let the calling application decide when all relevant parts of a transaction are complete and call the commit.

Comment: Do you want to update **all** `STAFFNO` where CLASSID = :NEW1.CLASSID or just the inserted ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I removed REFERENCING OLD as OLD1 as it has no meaning in an insert trigger):

```
create or replace TRIGGER ENFORCE_CLASS_TIMINGS 
BEFORE INSERT ON SYSTEM.TUTPRAC 
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW1
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ( 
  to_number(to_char(to_date(:NEW1.CLASS_TIME,'hh24:mi'),'sssss')) < 
    to_number(to_char(to_date('09:00', 'hh24:mi'), 'sssss')) OR
  to_number(to_char(to_date(:NEW1.CLASS_TIME,'hh24:mi'),'sssss')) > 
    to_number(to_char(to_date('18:00', 'hh24:mi'), 'sssss')))

BEGIN
  :NEW1.STAFFNO := NULL;
END;
```